# Which license of Visual Studio for online course?

Tags: visual-studio, license

I'm using the Community version of Visual Studio 2022 for creating some open source projects at home. Now I'd like to create some course about something related to Visual Studio and C++, and I'd like to know if in this case the Community version is good, of if I need to use a Professional license (I shall use the license that I've at work, I suppose).

I'm asking this because from one point of view I think that I need a commercial license since I hope to make money from the videotutorial, but from the other side I'm not creating commercial products by coding...

So what should I do in order to be ok with the license? Do I need a commercial one or I can use the Community edition for making the course?

Comment: Best to contact a Microsoft rep or retailer for licensing concerns

Comment: The community edition is fine. You do not need a commercial license in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consult the article
[License Terms | Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/)
which says:

> These license terms are an agreement between you and Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates). **They apply to the software named above**.

There are no license terms at all for the software you develop using
the community edition, so this software is entirely yours and you
posses the full copyright to it.